# OpenLayers 3: White gaps between OSM map tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3

As of openlayers 3.11, raster reprojection is introduced. I used OSM as a background layer and it works perfectly on some projection, such as EPSG:25832. Now I need to work on another projection EPSG:2326 but it shows some white gaps between map tiles when zoomed into the map.

I created a jsfiddle for reference, can someone help? Thanks!

```
var myMap = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [837814, 818872],
    projection: 'EPSG:2326',
    zoom: 19
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86Lu9nd7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in OpenLayers. See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4681 for its status.

Comment: I have same problem with Leaflet and I don't use OpenLayers. Any idea why?